# Specifying Point of Sale in Sabre Air Availability SOAP API

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to query class seat availability on specific flights using Sabre's Air Availability SOAP API.
I am getting expected result from the requests for our default point of sale. What I would like to know is how to use a specific point of sale for which to query availability.

e.g. Flight XY1234 from LAX to JFK on 01/10 has 8 seats available in class A for point of sale US. For point of sale RU it might have 10 seats.

Is there any way to specify that I want to retrieve availability for point of sale RU (or any other point of sale for that matter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which service are you using to request availability?

If using BFM (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max) your point of sale will be determined by the PseudoCityCode sent, as follows:

```
    <POS>
        <Source PseudoCityCode="**YourIPCCHere**">
        <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
            <CompanyName Code="TN" />
        </RequestorID>
        </Source>
    </POS>
```

If using OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/air_availability) your point of sale will be determined by the country associated to the PseudoCityCode sent during SessionCreateRQ (the service you use to get a session token in first place):
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/session_management/create_session

```
<SessionCreateRQ returnContextID="true">
  <POS>
    <Source PseudoCityCode="**YourIPCCHere**"/>
  </POS>
</SessionCreateRQ>
```

Comment: I'm using the OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ service, I should have specified that in the question. Sorry. And thank you for your answer!